# Converting a variable voltage to s stepped voltage

Tags: voltage

I want to design a circuit that takes a variable voltage (0 to 5v) and outputs a stepped voltage — 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 volts. So that the output voltage snaps to the closest whole number. It doesn't have to snap precisely — just provide a stepped range.

Thanks in advance!

James

Comment: You forgot to mention what your question is, you only described what you are planning to do.

Comment: Easiest way to do is to use one ADC and DAC, for reading the voltage and outputting the required voltage. Or you can use PWM for output of required voltage.

Comment: What sort of output current do you require? Do you want to use a microcontroller or keep this in the analogue domain? Is there a microcontroller elsewhere in your system that you could use to help?

Comment: You could get a set of regulators (one for each voltage you want) then use a series of comparators (opamps with a bias voltage that saturate when the voltage is over a threshold) and use these outputs with a few logic gates to switch relays on the regulators (don't have to use relays, you could use transistors) This means you don't need a micro controller to run the ADC/DAC stages. This method could use a micro controller to decode your comparator logic (still no need for ADC/DAC stage). Using regulators will means that the voltages you produce will have good characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

> So that the output voltage snaps to the closest whole number

The devil is in the detail and a basic comparator idea won't do this - it'll always snap to the threshold just exceeded. To be able to arbitrate between upper and lower levels is best done using a PIC (or equivalent micro) - use an analogue (ADC) input, get a 10 bit number (typically), round up or down to the nearest integer of the count of 5 and output a 1 on one of 5 digital lines. Weight the digital lines with resistors into a summing amplifier and this should work.

Of course there is also the LM3914 - it takes an analogue voltage of 0 to 5V and drives ten LEDs: -

[image]

If you group the LED outputs in pairs this can replace the PIC mentioned above. It works like this: -

[image]

Comment: you could use a comparator to 0.5V to snap to 1V, compare to 1.5V to snap to 2V etc. it just gets more complicated and less flexible

Comment: @PlasmaHH - funny enough I was just thinking about that when bingo, I remembered the LM3914.

Comment: So to the devilish details — it doesn't matter if it snaps to the closest — I just want it to step. The LM3914 seems like a good solution — even though I don't need all those outputs.

Comment: You said snap to the closest and that constitutes a spec LOL

Comment: I apologise :) - I guess I can use a LM339 using the same setup as the LM3914 - the only thing is that I can't output 1v from the LM3914. I guess I can do 2v and then halve it when putting it through the a summing op amp.

Comment: You can scale your summing op-amp correctly by choosing weighted values for the LM339 output pull-up resistors. Then the feedback resistor tunes that so that whatever comparator output voltage you have becomes 5V at the ouput when 5V is going into the comparators I reckon.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a couple of quad comparators (lm339) set to voltages of 1v, 2v, 3v, 4, 5v, then use a linear regulator and use the a bunch of resistor dividers to set different voltage outputs. pick a comparator with a pull down transistor output. this is theoretical as i have not tried it but it's a simple way to do what you want

alternatively use a microcontroller with an analogue to digital input. followed by my linear regulator idea.

note that to get one volt, you would have to pick a linear regulator with adjustable down to below one volt.

James

Comment: How do you switch in and out the different voltages provided by your resistor dividers? Also, resistor dividers are rather inefficient, and will have impedance issues depending on the load they see...

Comment: for a variable linear regulator the output voltage is between two resistors with the centre pin connected to the reference of the regulator. just like you can have a trim pot in a variable regulator circuit, you can have a row of carefully chosen resistors. i would connect each resistor to a small mosfet like a sn7002 or something similar to connect/disconnect it and change the voltage.